# How to reduce audios (MP3 files) loading time in android music player?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am developing music player for android. I wrote a code to fetch all audios from android phone (title, artist name, uri, album art).
But the problem is it takes more than 1 minute to load all songs.
How all music player apps handling this issue.
And is there any way to fetch or load one by one audio song and add to **RecyclerView**. Like Facebook new feeds. First it loads few stories when user scroll down it load few more stories.
Please help me to get of this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was while fetching album art it taking so much time.
I used Picasso library to fetch and display album art in recycler view.
I hope this question will help someone like me